# Read the raw value of a QDomElement

Tags: c++, qt, qtxml

I've an XML file from which i want to read the **raw value**. But Qt converts the value contents to a readable text...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<defaultcodec>UTF-8</defaultcodec>
<context>
    <name>AbstractAdjustageCommand</name>
    <message>
        <source>Press &quot;save&quot; to validate</source>
        <translation>Appuyez sur &lt;b&gt;enregistrer&lt;/b&gt;pour valider</translation>
    </message>
</context>
```

When i read the value with the following code :
`msgNode.firstChildElement("source").text();`

Then i've got the following result :
`Press "acquisition" to validate the measurement`

But, i really want to read the raw value and read the `Press &quot;save&quot; to validate` instead.

Is there a way to read the raw value of the QDomElement, or do I have to use another class in order to do that ?

Comment: Is it you, who create the XML file?

Comment: no, it's the translation files created by the Qt `lupdate` application.

Comment: Ok. You could do it by calling this `msgNode.firstChildElement("source").text().toHtmlEscaped()`. `QString::toHtmlEscaped()` function will escape special characters and you will get your "raw" string back.

Comment: Note that this will not bring back the exact number of whitespace, any `<![CDATA[...]]>` blocks, or custom entities.

Comment: yes, this works for that previous case, but, what about `&apos;` in the value... if i've got a special character like the `'` which is encoded with the escaped HTML `&apos;` then it is read as `'` and not `&apos;`